# How do I get mobile menu to drop down BEHIND navbar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

How can I get this mobile menu to slide down from behind the wood background but have the logo and mobile menu toggle still appear above the wooden background?

https://dev-hauls.andrichmedia.ca/

I've really been banging my head against the wall with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading into the z-index docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) as this will allow you to create the layering look you're going for!